# How can I use a CSS Selector to select a class name that changes dynamically?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse HTML like this:

```html
<div id="layers" class="r-1d2f490 r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-ipm5af r-184en5c" style=""><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-aqfbo4 r-1p0dtai r-1d2f490 r-12vffkv r-1xcajam r-zchlnj">
```

in my case, the class name changes continuously with every request, how I can parse this element?

I tried:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'r-1d2f490 r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-ipm5af r-184en5c"'})
print(container)
```

it sometimes yields a result, but sometimes it returns an empty list. How can I use a CSS selector with regex to scrape the class?

Answer (score 2):

Since your class name changes, try targeting the `id` (which should be unique) instead.

You can pass the *id* as a keyword argument to `.find()`.
In your case use `id="layers"`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("div", id="layers"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `class` attribute you have also `style` attribute and another `div`. If this is a typo, please correct it and give an example of code you want to parse so that we can do better research.

Comment: no it's not a typo it is a result of web page

Comment: I am talking about `attrs={'class':'r-1d2f490 r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-ipm5af r-184en5c" style=""><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-aqfbo4 r-1p0dtai r-1d2f490 r-12vffkv r-1xcajam r-zchlnj'}`. Could you please clarify how it depends on result from page?